Anaconda prompt vs command prompt difference
Does Anaconda prompt install on all the users on PC or just in its own environment?
If I download a module with pip install on Anaconda prompt would it work on my VSC Python?
I installed some modules with Anaconda prompt using pip. I'm now trying to use it on my VSC. Should it work or does Anaconda prompt effects only its environment like spyder?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Just select the conda environment in the Select Interpreter panel(Ctrl+Shift+P-->Python: Select Interpreter).

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
